# Compactness and the suspension of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I would like to prove the following statement: A topological space $X$ is compact if and only if its [suspension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_%28topology%29) $SX$ is compact.

The proof in one direction is pretty easy: If $X$ is compact, then $SX$ is compact since products of compact sets are compact, and quotients of compact sets are compact.

In the other direction, I had an idea, which I'll outline, but I'm not sure how to finish it it. I'm not sure if I can even use it, but here it is: The general idea is to write $X$ as a quotient of $SX$. I fix a point $y \in X$ and define the function $f: SX \rightarrow X$ by $f([x,t]):=x$, where $t\in(0,1)$; $f([x,1])=f([x,0])=y$. This function is well-defined and surjective, so I can impose the quotient topology on $X$. Then there's the issue of making sure the original topology on $X$ matches up with this one, and that's where I get stuck. Is there a choice of $y$ that can salvage this, or will I have to try something new?

Any hints or help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Closed subset of a compact Hausdorff space is ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotient thing is never going to work; just consider $X = S^1$.  Rather, from this example you can see that the relevant relationship is as a closed subset (the equator).

Comment: To that, I say "duh!" Can't believe I didn't see that! Thanks for the help, and for the nice counterexample to what I was trying to do.

Comment: In topology, always try the circle.